# how to make a graph with two lines and four symbols?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a graph with two lines (one for a level and anorther for other level of the factor), but each level have two categories on ggplot2. So I need make a graph like this (image) but with two symbols for each line. Help, please!!!!

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Please share some data with `dput()` and the code you tried.

Comment: I tried putting the data and ended up going as image. And the graph is an example of the internet.

Comment: Please consider [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I put a online table with the data.

Answer (score 0):

A (potential) solution in R base is this:

Define your data in a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Gender = c(rep("m",10), rep("f", 10)),
       Age = sample(10:90, 20, replace = T),
       Fitness_level = sample(1:10, 20, replace = T))
```

Add two distinct point characters depending on age level:

```
df$pch <- ifelse(df$Age > 40, 8, 12) # 8 and 12 are point characters
```

Plot fitness level against age for men and, respectively for women, adding for each a regression line:

```
# scatter plot:
plot(df$Fitness_level[df$Gender=="m"] ~ df$Age[df$Gender=="m"], pch = df$pch,     col="red", ylim=c(1,10))

# regression line for men:
abline(lm(df$Fitness_level[df$Gender=="m"] ~ df$Age[df$Gender=="m"]), col="red")

# add points for women:
points(df$Fitness_level[df$Gender=="f"] ~ df$Age[df$Gender=="f"], pch = df$pch, col = "blue")

# add regression line:
abline(lm(df$Fitness_level[df$Gender=="f"] ~ df$Age[df$Gender=="f"]), col="blue")
```

[image]